# Php sqlsrv search POST and GET Method multiple parameters

Tags: php, post, pagination, get, sqlsrv

First of all, i want to create a page that show a record of last one week from today date. Then, when user searching, it will show the specific record. The problem now is the pagination that i made clash through the last one week query, so the searching data cannot load its query bcs i set it up as POST method.

```
$name = null;
$id = null;
if(isset($_POST["search"]))
{
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $id = $_POST["id"];
}
if(isset($_GET["search"]))
{
    $name = $_GET["name"];
    $id = $_GET["id"];
}

$stmt = " SELECT c.* FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CustomerID) AS RowID,*  FROM customer  WHERE Name LIKE '%".$name."%' and  ID LIKE '%".$id."%' 
WHERE c.RowID > $row_start AND c.RowID <= $row_end";
```

This is if else statement

```
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
    if ($num_rows == 0) {
       echo "No data ";
       echo "<br/ >";
    } else {
        echo "<table style='border: 1px solid black;><tr>"
        . "<th><font color='white'>Student <br> ID</font></th>"
        . "<th><font color='white'>Name</font></th>"
        . " <th><font color='white'>Date</font></th>"
        . "</tr>";

        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<tbody style='border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; background-color: white'><tr>"
            . "<td align='center' for='Student_ID'>" . "<a href='http://localhost:808/jjjl/newdashboard/Studensdf.php?Student_ID=" . $row['Student_ID'] . "'>" . $row['Student_ID'] . "</a>" . "</td>"
            . "<td align='left'>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>"
            . "<td align='center' for='Dates'>" . $row['Dates']->format('d/m/Y') . "</td>";
        }

        echo "</tbody";
        echo "<br / >";
    }
} else {
    ?>

    <div class="col-md-12">
    <?php
    /*for last one week*/
    if ($num_rows1 == 0) {
        echo "No data for a week ago";
        echo "<br/ >";
    } else {
        echo "<table style='border: 1px solid black;><tr>"
        . "<th><font color='white'>Student <br> ID</font></th>"
        . "<th><font color='white'>Name</font></th>"
        . " <th><font color='white'>Date</font></th>". "</tr>";

        while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<tbody style='border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; background-color: white'><tr>"
            . "<td align='center' for='Student_ID'>" . "<a href='http://localhost:8080/hhol/nhhhboard/Stukhhtail.php?Student_ID=" . $row['Student_ID'] . "'>" . $row['Student_ID'] . "</a>" . "</td>"
            . "<td align='left'>" . $row['Name'] . "</td>"
            . "<td align='center' for='Dates'>" . $row['Dates']->format('d/m/Y') . "</td>";
        }

        echo "</tbody";
        echo "<br / >";
    }
}
```

And the form

```
<form name="frmSearch" class="form-horizontal" action="<?php echo $script; ?>" method="post"> 
    <label class="col-md-4">Student ID</label>: <input type="text" name="studentid" id="txtKeyword" value="<?php echo $studentid; ?>"><br>
    <label class="col-md-4">Name</label>: <input type="text" name="name" id="txtKeyword1" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search"></th>
```

and pagination

```
if ($prev_page) {
    echo " <a href='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$prev_page'><< Back</a> ";
}
for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_pages; $i++) {
    if ($i != $page) {
        echo "[ <a href='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$i&'>$i</a> ]";
    } else {
        echo "<b> $i </b>";
    }
}
if ($page != $num_pages) {
    echo " <a href ='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$next_page'>Next>></a> ";
}
sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

Comment: anyone have different ways?